# Loop through Database table to find all columns with fulfillment_status = 10. Do a task for each one... Laravel API

Tags: laravel, api

What is the most effective way of looping through an entire table with a foreach loop for the below DB query in Laravel?

- 1. Update 3rd party api with the details from orders table if order_status is 10
- 2. Set status from 10 - 20 if successful

```
public function create_the_api_fulfillment() {
  $order = DB::table('orders')
               ->where('fulfillment_status', '=', 10)
               ->pluck('refer_order_id')
               ->get(0);

  dd($order); // This gets the refer_order_id of the order with fulfillment_status 10 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  public function create_the_api_fulfillment() 
  {
     $orders = DB::table('orders')
                ->where('fulfillment_status', '=', 10)
                ->get();

     foreach($orders as $order)
     {
        if($order->order_status == 10)
        {
          $order->order_status = 20;
          $order->save();
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
public function create_the_api_fulfillment(){
    $orders = DB::table('orders')
                ->where('fulfillment_status', '=', 10)
                ->select('refer_order_id')
                ->get();
     foreach($orders as $order){
        if($order->order_status === 10){
            //update your api here
            $order->order_status = 20;
            $order->save();
        }
     }
  }
```